# Is Drupal suitable as a CMS for complex structured content?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

Having looked at the Drupal documentation and questions on this site, I'm still unclear as to whether Drupal is a suitable CMS for authoring complex structured content, so I was wondering if the Drupal experts could help me out?

I’m looking for a web-based authoring solution for very varied page types and therefore very different content models. Many, but not all, pages are similar to magazine articles with top-level metadata such as keywords, author and title then a series of ordered sections of various types that may contain other sections.

Specifically, I have pages with arbitrarily repeating polymorphic sections: for example, I have an article with sections. I want to add, remove, re-order and remove sections as I author my article. For each section I want to choose if the next section is a text section or an image section or a quote section, etc. I may want to change a text section to an image section. I have cases where there is deep nesting of these polymorphic sections. Some of the lower level section types are similar to XHTML elements in their structure such as lists and images, but there's a more constraint on the list of available elements and some bespoke structures alongside them.

I have content models for the pages represented using XML Schema, using xs:choice and xs:extension to represent the polymorphism. It's important that the content models are not compromised by forcing them into an authoring system which is not flexible enough to fit them as they are.

I'd be interested to know if Drupal is a suitable authoring environment for this type of content and if so which addons would be suitable to accomplish this?

Thanks.